# want to show skyscanner flight search widget results on same page

Tags: skyscanner

skyscanner flight search  widget show search results on skyscanner's website ... how to show search result on my website in same page . i dont want to redirect on skyscanner's website for results . my code widget code is

skyscanner.load("snippets","2");

```
        function main(){
            var snippet = new skyscanner.snippets.SearchPanelControl();
            snippet.setMarket("UK")
            snippet.setCulture("en-GB");
            snippet.setCurrency("GBP");
            snippet.setShape("box300x250");

            snippet.draw(document.getElementById("snippet_searchpanel"));
        }
        skyscanner.setOnLoadCallback(main);

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="snippet_searchpanel" style="width: auto; height:auto;"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Check with the service to see if they offer an API and integrate with that.  If they don't, you might try scraping data from their page in code and parsing what you need from it with a DOM parser.

Comment: i am new to these things ... will try this

Comment: you did this before ??